# Leave cell formatting intact

Tags: vba, excel

I have got this code:

```
With .Cells(i, 4)
    If .Value > 0.8 Then
        .Interior.Color = RGB(237, 67, 55) '<-- Red color
        .Font.Color = vbWhite

        ElseIf .Value > 0.6 Then
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 190, 0) '<-- Amber Colour
            .Font.Color = vbWhite

        ElseIf .Value2 = "---" Then
            .Interior.Color = .Interior.Color

        Else
            .Interior.Color = RGB(50, 205, 50) '<-- Green color
            .Font.Color = vbWhite
    End If
End With
```

The worksheet is already formatted to have alternating row colours by default but pending on the values of the cell the interior cell colour needs to change pending on the value of the cell but, some cells don't have numerical data and just `"---"`. When this is the case I want the original formatting to remain as it was before the code was run.

Basically, If the cell contains `"---"` don't assign any other interior colour, but keep the colour already assigned.

Comment: So what happens when it hits the third step of the if statement where it checks for "---"?

Comment: @tjb1 nothing, it just goes to the next part of the statment and then formats the "---" cells interior red

Comment: i have tried using .value and the .value2 as well with no luck

Comment: Is the `---` a mask for `0`?  should you be checking for `0` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this and it seemed to work on my test data, for some reason excel is treating "---" as a value larger than 0.8 so moving the check for "---" first will stop this.

```
With .Cells(i, 4)
    If .Value = "---" Then
            .Interior.Color = .Interior.Color

        ElseIf .Value > 0.8 Then
            .Interior.Color = RGB(237, 67, 55) '<-- Red color
            .Font.Color = vbWhite

        ElseIf .Value > 0.6 Then
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 190, 0) '<-- Amber Colour
            .Font.Color = vbWhite

        Else
            .Interior.Color = RGB(50, 205, 50) '<-- Green color
            .Font.Color = vbWhite

    End If
End With
```

Comment: that was it!... dont understand why it would not read it before. your code woked but it didnt retail the original format colour so i added the following code and it worked:
   ` If .Value = "---" Then
            If .Interior.Color <> vbWhite Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(220, 230, 241)
            End If`